# Applying a land-sea mask to netCDF data in Python

Tags: python, numpy, netcdf, python-xarray

I'm trying to apply a land/sea mask to some data from a netCDF file. The code I have works, but modifies the files on disk. I would like to be able to do it in memory, but the variables have shapes like `(240, 46, 400, 568)` and even just running `np.zeros` to try something like

```
with Dataset('parameters/masks.nc', 'r') as mask, Dataset('remapped/' + ifile, 'a') as to_mask:
    masked_data = np.zeros(to_mask['alk'].shape)
    if len(to_mask['alk'].shape) == 4:  # The dimensions are time,depth,lat,lon
        for i in range(0, to_mask[var].shape[0]):
            masked_data[i, :, :, :] = ma.masked_where(
                np.logical_not(np.array(mask['tmask'][0, :, :, :], dtype=bool)),
                np.array(to_mask[var][i, :, :, :]))[:]
```

gives me a `MemoryError`. It seems kind of odd to me, because right after I can load the data and use it with no memory issues.

I've started to look at xarray, as it seems to have some functions I'll want to use to process the data like easy time averaging, but there doesn't seem to be a straight forward way to apply a mask like I'm trying to.

Current Code:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np

with Dataset('parameters/masks.nc', 'r') as mask, Dataset('remapped/' + ifile, 'a') as to_mask:
    for var in to_mask.variables:
        if len(to_mask[var].shape) == 4:  # The dimensions are time,depth,lat,lon
            for i in range(0, to_mask[var].shape[0]):
                to_mask[var][i, :, :, :] = ma.masked_where(
                    np.logical_not(np.array(mask['tmask'][0, :, :, :], dtype=bool)),
                    np.array(to_mask[var][i, :, :, :]))[:]
```

Answer (score 1):

As per usual, just banging your head in to a problem for a few more hours can help. My working code (excuse the changes variable names ect) uses xarray as I had thought.

```
import xarray as xr

with xr.open_dataset(mask_file) as m_f, xr.open_dataset(input_file) as i_f:
    mask = m_f['tmask'][0, :, :, :].values
    data = i_f[var].where(mask)
```